# Why this code is not entering the username and password?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
#from secrets import pw

class instagrambot:

    def __init__(self,user,passw):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
       # sleep(2)
        #self.driver.find_element("//input[@name=\"username\"]")\.send_keys(username)
        #self.driver.find_element("//input[@name=\"password\"]")\.send_keys(pw)
        #self.driver.find_element('//Button[@type="submit"]')\.click()

        username_input = self.driver.find_element("input[name='username']")
        password_input = self.driver.find_element("input[name='password']")

        username_input.send_keys(user)
        password_input.send_keys(passw)

        login_button = self.driver.find_element("//button[@type='submit']")
        login_button.click()

        sleep(4)


instagrambot("","") #for some privacy issue's i have not filled the username and password
```

**The problem is the code open's the chrome and instagram.com but it does no enterts the username and password! **

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
#from secrets import pw

class instagrambot:

    def __init__(self,user,passw):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

        self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        sleep(5)
       # sleep(2)
        #self.driver.find_element("//input[@name=\"username\"]")\.send_keys(username)
        #self.driver.find_element("//input[@name=\"password\"]")\.send_keys(pw)
        #self.driver.find_element('//Button[@type="submit"]')\.click()

        username_input = self.driver.find_element_by_name("username")
        password_input = self.driver.find_element_by_name("password")

        username_input.send_keys(user)
        password_input.send_keys(passw)

        login_button = self.driver.find_element_by_type("submit")
        login_button.click()

        sleep(4)


instagrambot("sss","dd")
```

Comment: it's working now thankyou :)

Comment: yeah it fill's the username and password but it does't logging in :(